# FormsAuthenticationTicket Not passing role to global.asax using Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating role manullay using FormsAuthenticationTicket. I have 2 roles (admin and user). I try to set role using FormAuthenticationTicket but failed. No role pass in global.asax file...

Here is my code: (Login Controller Class)

```
        string[] names = new string[2] { "admin", "user"};
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        version: 1,
        name: loginmodel.Email,
        issueDate: DateTime.Now,
        expiration: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        isPersistent: false,
        userData: String.Join("|", names));

                var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

when i check ticket data: It contains UserData = "admin|user" but empty in global file.

Global.asax Code:

```
 public override void Init()
    {

        base.AuthenticateRequest += OnAuthenticateRequest;
    }

    private void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                var decodedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
                var roles = decodedTicket.UserData.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                var principal = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, roles);
                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }
    }
```

In var decodeTicket = UserData is always null :(

Comment: This should be done in `protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: still not working @StephenMuecke

Comment: Did you try protected void Application_OnAuthenticateRequest(Object src, EventArgs e)?